# Python __slots__ doesn't work with a certain class declaration

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I declare the class in python as below **slots** work

```
class CSStudent(object):
stream = 'cse'
__slots__ = ['name', 'roll']

def __init__(self, name, roll):
    self.name = name
    self.roll = roll
```

When I declare the class in python as below **slots** doesn't work

```
   class CSStudent:
stream = 'cse'
__slots__ = ['name', 'roll']

def __init__(self, name, roll):
    self.name = name
    self.roll = roll
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?
Also - any chance you could remove the preceding three whitespaces before `class` and try it again? As is, the indentation looks like a cause for headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Two things seem to have triggered your error:

First, the missing brackets from the `class` declaration.

Second, your indents were way out of line. Four spaces for each new block of code.

```
class CSStudent(object):
    stream = 'cse'
    __slots__ = ['name', 'roll']

    def __init__(self, name, roll):
        self.name = name
        self.roll = roll 

user247=CSStudent('user247',2018)

print user247.name,' | ',user247.roll
```

When you run this, works just fine:

```
$ chmod +x /tmp/slots_test.py 
$ /tmp/slots_test.py 
user247  |  2018
```

Comment: I think this answer misses the point in a couple ways. The `__slots__` attribute in the class doesn't *do* anything. You're still able to add extra instance attributes as much as you want (try `user247.foo = "bar"`). Using `__slots__` in a new-style class would prevent that. Also, you've complained about the question's indentation, but the indentation in your code is also wrong (you haven't indented the `stream` or `__slots__` lines).

Comment: You are right. I did miss the `object` inheritance. The indentation I fixed twice beforehand but the editor seems to live a life of its own. I had that before. Thanks for the correction anyway, hopefully, I did it right in the code this time.

Answer (score 1):

The `__slots__` attribute only works in "new-style" classes (which are not really "new", they came out in Python 2.2 more than 15 years ago). In Python 2, you only get a new-style class if you inherit from `object` (or from some other new-style class). Inheritance is declared by putting one or more base classes in parentheses after the derived class's name in the `class` statement. So your second implementation of `CSStudent` is not a new-style class, since it does not inherit from anything. Thus `__slots__` won't work (it will just be a weirdly named attribute).

The distinction between new-style and old-style classes only exists on Python 2. Python 3 has dropped old-style classes, so both of your class implementations would work the same in a Python 3 interpreter (it's no longer required to explicitly inherit from `object`).